# Remove the filename from the path

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am writing a maintenance plan where databases will be detached then the content of the folder it resided in will be moved to another drive for archiving.

```
declare @db varchar(500), @path varchar(max), @SQL varchar(max)

declare u_cur cursor fast_forward for
    select name, [filename] from #DbsToBeDetached
open u_cur

fetch next from u_cur into @db, @path
while (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
begin
    SET @SQL = 'ALTER DATABASE ' + @db + ' SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;'

    EXEC(@SQL)      

    EXEC sp_detach_db @db, 'true';

    set @path = MagicFunction(@path)

    exec sp_xp_cmdshell 'move /Y "' + @path + '" "e:\archive\"' + @db + '"'

    fetch next from u_cur into @db, @path
end
close u_cur
deallocate u_cur
```

The only thing I am stuck on is what do I do where it says `MagicFunction` to turn a path like

```
D:\data\conversions\wi_sql2005\30950 example database\30950_data.mdf
```

to

```
D:\data\conversions\wi_sql2005\30950 example database
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a function using the following logic (or just use the SQL inline):

```
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(100)
SET     @fileName = 'D:\data\conversions\wi_sql2005\30950 example database\30950_data.mdf'
SELECT LEFT(@fileName, LEN(@fileName) - CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(@fileName)))
```

Comment: The logic is backwards as I need the path not the file but I think that will work.

Comment: I think you are doing the opposite. OP wants PATH minus file name.

Comment: I edited your answer as you where 99% there but you gave the wrong side of the / I will accept after the 5 min.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, Thanks! I totally read it wrong. You beat me to the update, thanks very much! I've updated the post as well. You can also use the `REPLACE` function.

Comment: @James Hill would advise against the replace version in the general case (it would work for me for my specific case) as what if in the file path it has the same name as the file (remember files don't have to have extensions) `D:\example\thisWouldFail\thisWouldFail`

Answer (score 2):

OK, I think this is basically what you want (but it could be improved upon).

```
DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(200)

SET @path = 'D:\data\conversions\wi_sql2005\30950 example database\30950_data.mdf'

DECLARE @rec NVARCHAR(200)
SET @rec = REVERSE(@path)

DECLARE @Pos INT

SET @pos = CHARINDEX('\', @rec)
SET @rec = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@rec, @pos + 1, LEN(@rec)))

PRINT @rec
```

Comment: Reduce it down to one SET statement (albeit a long one), and you'd have how I implemented this one.

Answer (score 1):

I've added some CLR regex functions to My sql instance.  I would suggest that, then you could say something like...

```
SET PATH = MagicFunctionsDB.schema.regexStrMatch(origfilename,'^.+(?=\\)',1 --indicates case sensitivity)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably an easier way to do this that i am unaware of but you can split on the "\" character. In this case you would have an array of 6 variables something like paths(5). Then, rebuild your string by doing something like

```
For each Path in paths(5) - 1
   myPath = myPath + Path
Next
```

You basically are breaking down your path into each directory. Then rebuilding the path but leaving off the filename portion at the end. Hope that helps.